# Push Notification from Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, push-notification, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

We are getting tons of log file every day. I'm working on an app that uses Kafka to feed the data to Apache Spark for real-time processing. The actual idea is to process the log files inside Spark and recognize the pattern. I can gather insights with the Spark processing.

Now I want to establish a notification mechanism. So when Spark processes the incoming log and if it finds a critical event, it should send an alert. I want that alert to be delivered as a push notification. How can I achieve this?

PS: I'm able to send an email alert. I have that thing ready, but push notification could be a big thing. So help me out!

Comment: In foreachRDD you can use `rdd.foreachPartition`, in lambda you can create KafkaProducer and send some message to specified topic. Is it what you want? BTW. Remember that Spark currently* is near-real-time, so lag will be not in ms but seconds. * - currently, because RISELab is preparing changes to provide full-real-time :)

Comment: No.. Kafka producer sends the log files and  I'm consuming them in Spark. I want to do processing and when there is a critical event, I want to send a push notification. My question is can we send that notification from Spark itself?

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman, sorry for picking up this aged thread. Didn't you eventually manage to push notification from spark jobs? Can you elaborate how you achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check one app out. This app reads (push or pull) or writes to Kafka and all processing can be done inside (internal engine) in a memory cluster structure with very high frequency capacity (one of case is like 2.5 billion rows of log file processing in a day in real time). It creates mail, sms, rdbms dmls, web site pop-ups etc. as an action as output. Here is the link to app called [evam](http://www.evam.com).